# Get text given item index GtkComboBoxText

Tags: gtk3

I am looking for something like

```
gchar *
gtk_combo_box_text_get_text (GtkComboBoxText *combo_box, int index);
```

It looks like there is no such method. How do I emulate it? Is the proper solution to change the active index, retreiv the text, and then reset active index?